# Regex: Select the first line in the file which is followed by a blank line

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

`Tablourilor pe care le numim în ulei încep prin folosirea apei`

`Remarcăm că marea majoritate a tablourilor pe care le numim „în ulei“ încep prin folosirea apei. TEXT. TEXT. Remarcăm că marea majoritate a tablourilor pe care le numim „în ulei“ încep prin folosirea apei. TEXT. TEXT. Remarcăm că marea majoritate a tablourilor pe care le numim „în ulei“ încep prin folosirea apei. TEXT. TEXT.`

So, I have 3 blank lines, then a simple line (without dot), then another blank line, then text.

I want to select the line which is followed by a blank line, then by a text. In my case,

**THE OUTPUT MUST BE:**

`Tablourilor pe care le numim în ulei încep prin folosirea apei`

My regex is not so good:

FIND: `\A.*\s+\w+.*$\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `\R\R\R\K.+(?=\R\R.+)`
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Find Next</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R\R\R          # 3 linebreaks
\K              # forget them (reset operator)
.+              # 1 or more any character but newline (i.e. the line to be searched)
(?=\R\R.+)      # positive lookahead, make sure we have 2 linebreaks and some text after
```

If the first 3 lines contain white spaces, you have to use this regex:

```
(?:\h*\R){3}\K.+(?=\R\R.+)
```

Where:

```
(?:      # non capture group
  \h*      # 0 or more horizontal spaces
  \R       # any kind of linebreak
){3}     # end group, must appear 3 times
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: hi @Toto. Something strange, doesn't work to me.

Comment: I see now, WORKS if the lines are complete BLANKS, not with empty spaces. And a little shorter version for your regex should be: `\s+\K.+(?=\R\R.+)` THANKS

Comment: @JustMe: Take care that the shorter regex matches even if there is not 3 linebreaks. If the lines contain spaces, you can use: `(?:\h*\R){3}\K.+(?=\R\R.+)`

Comment: SUPER. Can you update your main answer and put also this alternative answer?

Comment: @JustMe: Done ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

- Find what: `^.+$(?=\R\R)`
- Search mode regular expression

Comment: your regex almost good if I use `(.matches newsline)` option on FIND. But this will select all line before text, and I need to find ONLY that particular line before text.

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

Find what:

Search mode regular expression (.matches newsline)

`(\s+)\s(\w.*?$)(?=\R\R)\1`

**OR**

`(\s+)(.+$)(\s+)(?=\R\R)\2`